# Outlining and aligning a Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

Bear with me as this is a multi-part question. **First I'm trying figure out how to outline a matrix and not change the style of the nodes in the matrix.** Maybe a better question is how to configure a node/matrix w/o changing anything within its scope.

**Secondly I'd like the top of the 2nd/right matrix to be on the same y-coordinate as `c.south`** I tried to accomplish this with `positioning` via `right = of c.south`, but it does this strange overlap thing and changes the anchor from the node origin to the node's west anchor. (The blue dots are the anchor point currently being used)

[image]

Below is the way I want it to look in the end, which I forced by using `right = of c.south east, anchor = north west` in the options of `mtrx2` This pushes the anchors to the wrong spot (which I don't want) **So is there a better way of positioning the matrix like this?**

[image: north west]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%\input{../tikz-setup.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, 
                        draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em ,
                        minimum width = 6em,
                        inner sep = 5pt
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 3pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]
\tikzstyle{data}    = [ trapezium, 
                        draw, 
                        trapezium left angle=60, 
                        trapezium right angle=120pt,
                        minimum height = 6em, 
                       % text width = 5em
                       ]
\tikzstyle{line}    = [ draw, -triangle 45 ]

\tikzstyle{list}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        minimum width = 6em                      
                      ]

\tikzstyle{ptr-box}  = [ rectangle, 
                        text width = 8em                      
                      ]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = flush center, font = \small]
    % Place nodes
    \matrix [column sep = 0.5em, row sep = 1.3em] (mtrx1)
    {  
    \node [state] (a) {a}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
    \node [data] (b) {b}; \\
    \node [test] (c) {c}; \\
    \node [action] (d) {d}; \\
    \node [test] (e) {e}; \\
    \node [action] (f) {f}; \\
    \node [action] (g) {g}; \\
    }; 

    \matrix [column sep = 0.5em, row sep = 1.3em, right = of c.south, draw, dashed] (mtrx2)
    { 
    &      
    \node [test] (aa) {aa}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
    &
    \node [test] (bb) {bb}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
    &
    \node [action] (cc) {cc}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
    &
    \node [data] (dd) {dd}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
    \node [state] (ee) {ee}; &
    \node [state] (ff) {ff};\fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
    }; 

    % Draw edges
    \path [draw] (a) -- (g);    
    \path [draw] (aa) -- (ff);



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use distances to explicitly input shift amount and you can use the `nodes={}` to override general options. That's why `matrix of nodes` key is important.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning,matrix}

\tikzset{
state/.style={rounded rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=3em ,minimum width = 6em, inner sep = 5pt},
test/.style = {diamond, draw, shape aspect=2, inner sep = 0pt,text width = 7em,text centered},
action/.style ={rectangle, draw,text width=8em,inner sep = 3pt, minimum height=5em},
data/.style = {trapezium, draw, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120pt, minimum height = 6em},
line/.style = {draw, -triangle 45},
list/.style = {rectangle, draw,minimum width = 6em},
ptr-box/.style = {rectangle, text width = 8em}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font = \small]
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, column sep = 0.5em, row sep = 1.3em] (mtrx1)
    {  
    |[state]| a\\
    |[data]|  b\\
    |[test]|  c\\
    |[action]|d\\
    |[test]|  e\\
    |[action]|f\\
    |[action]|g\\
    }; 

    \matrix [matrix of nodes,column sep = 0.5em, row sep = 1.3em, 
    draw, dashed,
    nodes = {solid,red}, %<- Overrides
    right = 2cm of mtrx1-3-1.south, %How much further from right of the node...
    anchor = north west,
    ] (mtrx2)
    {
                    &|[state]| aa\\
                    &|[test]|  bb\\
                    &|[action]|cc\\
                    &|[data]|  dd\\
    |[state]|  ee   &|[state]| ff\\
    }; 

    % Draw edges
    \path [draw] (mtrx1-1-1) -- (mtrx1-7-1);    
    \path [draw] (mtrx2-1-2) -- (mtrx2-5-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Implemented this in my flow-chart but I'm curious what's is going on w/ `d, f, g, & cc` in your edit to my example?

Comment: @blitzvergnugen You have a large text box (8em) and it starts to write from the left of it. Include more text and it will be apparent or align it to the center.

Comment: Ah. So because the styles inside the `matrix of nodes` are defined by only `nodes={}` the `align=flush center` I have in the `\begin{tikzpicture}` isn't being applied. Is that correct?

Comment: @blitzvergnugen Oh, I think I've removed it aacidentally. Sorry about that. But in general, the last setting overrides whatever comes before it. So if you use another `align` key for the matrix then you would be right, it would be overridden. Note however that `nodes={}` is an append style so it would add the properties to the existing ones. So if the overall matrix didn't have draw option we should have additionally provided it because it's not inherited from the big matrix.